# Boost.Python custom converter

Tags: c++, python, boost, binding, boost-python

I have a class taking a vector as parameter (a binary file content).

I would like to convert python 'str' type into vector of unsigned char but only for one of my class method.

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello) {  class_<Hello>("Hello").
     // This method takes a string as parameter and print it
     .def("printChar", &Hello::printChar)
     // This method takes a vector<unsigned char> parameter
     .def("storeFile", &Hello::storeFile) }
```

Using custom converter seems to be what I need but if I modify my boost::python::converter::registry it will be modify for all my calls to printChar and all python methods passing string as parameter will be converted to vector.

How can I register a per-method converter ?

Answer (score 15):

There are two approaches to this problem:

- Export a helper function as `Hello.storeFile` that accepts `boost::python::str`, constructs `std::vector<unsigned char>` from the string, and delegates to the C++ `Hello::storeFile` member function.
- Write a custom converter.  While converters cannot be registered on a per-function basis, they are fairly well scoped as to not perform any unintended conversions.  This approach often provides more reusability.

---

#### Helper Function

Using a helper function will not affect any other exported function.  Thus, the conversion between a python string and `std::vector<unsigned char>` will only occur for `Hello.storeFile`.

```
void Hello_storeFile(Hello& self, boost::python::str str)
{
  std::cout << "Hello_storeFile" << std::endl;
  // Obtain a handle to the string.
  const char* begin = PyString_AsString(str.ptr());
  // Delegate to Hello::storeFile().
  self.storeFile(std::vector<unsigned char>(begin, begin + len(str)));
}

...

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  python::class_<Hello>("Hello")
    // This method takes a string as parameter and print it
    .def("printChar", &Hello::printChar)
    // This method takes a vector<unsigned char> parameter
    .def("storeFile", &Hello_storeFile)
    ;
}
```

---

#### Custom Converter

A converter registration has three parts:

- A function that checks if a `PyObject` is convertible.  A return of `NULL` indicates that the `PyObject` cannot use the registered converter.
- A construct function that constructs the C++ type from a `PyObject`.  This function will only be called if `converter(PyObject)` does not return `NULL`.
- The C++ type that will be constructed.

Therefore, for a given C++ type, if `converter(PyObject)` returns a non-`NULL` value, then `construct(PyObject)` will create the C++ type.  The C++ type serves as a key into the registry, so Boost.Python should not perform unintended conversions.

In context of the question, we want a converter for `std::vector<unsigned char>` where `converter(PyObject)` returns non-`NULL` if `PyObject` is a `PyString`, and `converter(PyObject)` will use `PyObject` to create and populate `std::vector<unsigned char>`.  This conversion will only occur if for exported C++ functions that have a `std::vector<unsigned char>` (or a const reference) parameter and the argument provided from python is a string.  Therefore, this custom converter will not affect exported functions that have `std::string` parameters.

Here is a complete example.  I have opted to make the converter generic to allow multiple types to be constructable from a python string.  With its chaining support, it should have the same feel as other Boost.Python types.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

class Hello
{
public:
  void printChar(const std::string& str)
  {
    std::cout << "printChar: " << str << std::endl;
  }

  void storeFile(const std::vector<unsigned char>& data)
  {
    std::cout << "storeFile: " << data.size() << ": ";
    BOOST_FOREACH(const unsigned char& c, data)
      std::cout << c;
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
};

/// @brief Type that allows for conversions of python strings to
//         vectors.
struct pystring_converter
{

  /// @note Registers converter from a python interable type to the
  ///       provided type.
  template <typename Container>
  pystring_converter&
  from_python()
  {
    boost::python::converter::registry::push_back(
      &pystring_converter::convertible,
      &pystring_converter::construct<Container>,
      boost::python::type_id<Container>());
    return *this;
  }

  /// @brief Check if PyObject is a string.
  static void* convertible(PyObject* object)
  {
    return PyString_Check(object) ? object : NULL;
  }

  /// @brief Convert PyString to Container.
  ///
  /// Container Concept requirements:
  ///
  ///   * Container::value_type is CopyConstructable from char.
  ///   * Container can be constructed and populated with two iterators.
  ///     I.e. Container(begin, end)
  template <typename Container>
  static void construct(
    PyObject* object,
    boost::python::converter::rvalue_from_python_stage1_data* data)
  {
    namespace python = boost::python;
    // Object is a borrowed reference, so create a handle indicting it is
    // borrowed for proper reference counting.
    python::handle<> handle(python::borrowed(object));

    // Obtain a handle to the memory block that the converter has allocated
    // for the C++ type.
    typedef python::converter::rvalue_from_python_storage<Container>
                                                                 storage_type;
    void* storage = reinterpret_cast<storage_type*>(data)->storage.bytes;

    // Allocate the C++ type into the converter's memory block, and assign
    // its handle to the converter's convertible variable.  The C++
    // container is populated by passing the begin and end iterators of
    // the python object to the container's constructor.
    const char* begin = PyString_AsString(object);
    data->convertible = new (storage) Container(
      begin,                          // begin
      begin + PyString_Size(object)); // end
  }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  // Register PyString conversions.
  pystring_converter()
    .from_python<std::vector<unsigned char> >()
    .from_python<std::list<char> >()
    ;

  python::class_<Hello>("Hello")
    // This method takes a string as parameter and print it
    .def("printChar", &Hello::printChar)
    // This method takes a vector<unsigned char> parameter
    .def("storeFile", &Hello::storeFile)
    ;
}
```

And the example usage:

```
>>> from hello import Hello
>>> h = Hello()
>>> h.printChar('abc')
printChar: abc
>>> h.storeFile('def')
storeFile: 3: def
>>> h.storeFile([c for c in 'def'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Hello.storeFile(Hello, list)
did not match C++ signature:
    storeFile(Hello {lvalue}, std::vector<unsigned char, 
                                          std::allocator<unsigned char> >)
```

For more on custom converters and C++ containers, consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15940413/1053968) answer.