# Boost Python - Cast to incomplete class

Tags: python, boost

Is there a way to cast between classes where only the interface is known in boost python?

Consider the following example:

```
// ---------- Module A ----------

class A_ifc
{
public:
    virtual int foo() = 0;
};

class A_impl : public A_ifc
{
public:
    int foo() {...}
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Module_A)
{
    class_<A_impl, boost::noncopyable>("A", no_init)
        .def("foo", &A_impl::foo)
    ;
}

// ---------- Module B ----------

class B_ifc
{
public:
    virtual int cross_module_operation(A_ifc* a) = 0;
};

class B_impl : public B_ifc
{
public:
    int cross_module_operation(A_ifc* a) {...}
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Module_B)
{
    class_<B_impl, boost::noncopyable>("B", no_init)
        .def("cross_module_operation", &B_impl::cross_module_operation)
    ;
}
```

In my C code none of the classes know anything of each other except for their respective interfaces (here 'A_ifc' and 'B_ifc'). All cross-module operations pass only interface pointers.
When I want to achieve the same behavior in Python however this wouldn't work, because for Boost Python the whole class definition must be known for every referenced class.

I have already tried opaque pointers (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/return_opaque_pointer.html), but whenever I compile any Boost code that contains "boost::python::return_value_policy", the application crashes with an access violation on startup.
I also looked into custom converters (see [Boost.Python custom converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105539/boost-python-custom-converter)), but I have no idea how to apply this concept to my problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, casting to a an abstract base class is indeed possible as long as as run-time type information is enabled.

In other words this will work: `objects::register_conversion<A_impl, A_ifc>();`

I feel a bit silly for not having tried such an obvious solution earlier.