# Extract and convert list element of boost::python::list

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I have heterogeneous list of `int` and `string` I want to store all of them in `vector<string>`.
With this command:

```
    std::string temp = boost::python::extract<std::string>(xList[i][j]);
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: No registered converter was able to produce a C++ rvalue of type std::string from this Python object of type float
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices: either get the values as `boost::python::object` and check the types and do whatever you like, or [register a converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105539/boost-python-custom-converter) that turns numbers into strings (using `std::to_string` presumably).

You can use the instructions for "Extracting C++ Types" in the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/object.html#python.extracting_c___objects):

```
extract<std::string&> extractor(xList[i][j]);
if (extractor.check()) {
    std::string& v = extractor();
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I get it as `boost::python::object` and check the types?

Comment: Why the string is defined as reference?