# boost::python pass list of lists to c++ function

Tags: python, boost-python

I am playing with boost.python and I have the following question:

in python I have a list of lists:

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

I have a c++ function like:

```
void do(std::vector<std::vector<int>> v);
```

Obviously I cannot pass l to the above function.

How I can pass a list of list to a function as above?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15940413/1053968) demonstrates using custom converters to convert iterable Python objects into C++ sequences.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Feeding a Python list into a function taking in a vector with Boost Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842126/feeding-a-python-list-into-a-function-taking-in-a-vector-with-boost-python)